# how to make quotes a string in python

Tags: python

how to process quotes issue in this question?

```
class Solution:
    # @param strs: A list of strings
    # @return: A list of strings
    def anagrams(self, strs):
        # write your code here
        dic = {}
        result = []

        for s in strs:
            if s == '""':
                key ='""'
            else:
                key = ''.join(sorted(s))
            dic[key].add(s)
        for key, value in dic.iteritems():
            if len(value) > 1:
                result.append(value)
        return result
```

Input

```
["",""]
```

Expected

```
["",""]
```

Error Message

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "Main.py", line 7, in ans = Solution().anagrams(strs) File "Solution.py", line 14, in anagrams dic[key].add(s) KeyError: '' EXITCODE=1
```

Answer (score 1):

When you write `["",""]`, the elements of the input array are empty strings -- the `""` are not part of the string contents. So `s = '""'` will not match them. You need to write:

```
if s == '':
```